# Why does the next() method fail after the last record, using arcpy.da.SearchCursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, stopiteration

Using the older [arcpy.SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000070000000), the `next()` method would return `Nothing` once the last record had been passed.

Using the newer [arcpy.da.SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/), I'm finding that the next() method crashes the script if there are no more records. To illustrate:

```
import arcpy
fc = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcGlobeData\continent.shp"
fields = ["CONTINENT"]
where = "CONTINENT = 'Asia'"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, where) as cursor:
    for i in range(0,5):
        row = cursor.next()
        print row
```

There is only one record in the cursor, so the first time it iterates the name is printed. But the second iteration throws a StopIteration error.

How should we use `next()` with `arcpy.da.SearchCursor?`

Comment: This is more a generic Python question that it is GIS-specific. I'm sorry this tripped you up at first, but it's behaving exactly like any reasonably designed API in Python would with regards to the iterator protocol.

Comment: The line between spatial analysis and programming is very thin.

Comment: @JasonScheirer maybe - but I didn't find anything when searching on arcpy.da.SearchCursor and next. I'm not an expert Python programmer so I didn't know to look up Python Iterator Protocol, etc. At least now it's available if someone searches on those keywords

Answer (score 4):

I can't see this documented in the Esri help files, so I'm entering it here for posterity.

According to Jason Scheirer from the Esri ArcPy team this is the intended behaviour ([original Esri forums post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/108627)):

> The `.next()` method raises an error by design: it follows to the letter [the Python Iterator Protocol](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/), which requires the `.next()` method on an object to raise a `StopIteration` exception when it is exhausted.

The suggested approach is to use a `for` iterator on the cursor, ie without using the next() method at all:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
```

In my case I wanted to perform an action when there was no row - I found that a Try, Except block worked well:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, where) as cursor:
    try:
        row = cursor.next()
        print(row)
    except StopIteration:
        print("No rows")
    except:
        print("something else went wrong")
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, what type is `row` after the final entry?

Comment: @nickves: It's still a list.

Comment: I really wouldn't call using a `for` loop a _workaround_, I'd call it the _expected behavior_.

Comment: @JasonScheirer fair enough - it was a workaround for what I was trying to do, but I agree in most cases it's better to use the for loop. I've modified the answer

Comment: Also you can implement a simple conditional: `if len(cursor) == 0: do stuff; break`

Comment: @nickves actually I don't think that's correct - the cursor doesn't have a length property

Comment: @StephenLead Yes I see now; but how can one check then if the cursor has returned zero results then? Is there a .count() method of cursors?

Comment: @nickves aha - that's exactly what I'm trying to detect too! The code block above does this - if there are zero results (or you have iterated through all results to the end of the cursor) calling cursor.next() throws the StopIteration error.

Comment: If you need to get the length you need to run the cursor out and count. `rows = list(cursor); print len(rows)`.

Comment: @JasonScheirer would `for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields)` work? Even more concise.

Comment: @sgillies: Yes. A plain old `for` loop would work. The `with` guard just guarantees the connections get closed, without it if some user code threw an error in a `for` loop the cursor wouldn't get closed until it was manually closed or garbage collected.